# How to mark an order failed programmatically - Magento

Tags: php, magento

I would just like to know what is that one property which when set would mark the order as failed so that `failureAction()` of `app/code/core/Mage/Checkout/controller/OnepageController.php` gets called.

I have an Observer.php where in I'm creating invoice for successful payments and for failed payments saving order with `pending_payment` status and wanting to redirect them to the cart page with an error message at the top.

All this happens fine. Just that for unsuccessful / failed payments, along with saving the order with pending_payment status n redirecting them to cart page with error message, I would also like to retain/save the cart from getting empty.

But to no luck

Observer.php

```
 public function implementOrderStatus($event)
 {
    $order = $event->getEvent()->getOrder(); 
    if ($this->_getPaymentMethod($order) == 'mypaymentmodule') 
    {
                $quote = Mage::getModel('sales/quote')->load($order->getQuoteId());
        if($order->getPayment()->getCcTransId() == NULL)
        {
            $order->cancel();
            $order->setStatus('canceled');
            $order->save();
            $quote->setIsActive(1)->save();
            /*$state = 'pending_payment';
            $status = 'pending_payment';
            $comment = 'Payment transaction failed due to incorrect AVS/CVD details.';
            $isNotified = false;
            $order->setState($state,$status,$comment,$isNotified)->save();
            $order->setCanSendNewEmailFlag(false);*/

            Mage::getSingleton('checkout/session')->addError('Sorry, either of your card information (billing address or card validation digits) dint match. Please try again');                 

            Mage::app()->getFrontController()->getResponse()->setRedirect('checkout/cart/')->sendResponse();
        }
       else
       {
           if ($order->canInvoice())

            $this->_processOrderStatus($order);
       }
    }
    return $this;
}
```

But `$quote->setIsActive(true)->save()` does not seem to be doing the trick. Any help as to how can I save my cart from getting empty after saving the order with 'canceled' status.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You maybe should have a look at `./app/code/core/Mage/Sales/Model/Order.php`. There you will find several constants for an order, which may be used to set the state of an order like this:

```
<?php
// [...] all your code within your custom action or script

//load your order by order_id (or by increment_id, if you like to, here, it's your order id
$order = Mage::getModel('sales/order')->load($your_order_id);
$order->setState(Mage_Sales_Model_Order::STATE_CANCELED); //or whatever distinct order status you'd like
$order->save();
```

The `failureAction` in the controiller action does nothing of the sort, if you want to call it manually, you can build it's url using `Mage::getUrl()`

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I have already tried the code you have suggested but that does not take me to the failure page. What I really want to do is save the cart i.e. `$quote->setIsActive(true)->save()` to save the cart from getting empty on a failed/canceled order so that the customer does not have to go thru the hassle of adding the items again. Any ideas to do that?

Comment: which event does the observer listen to? You might be able to through an exception from it along sending a header changing the location back to the cart.

Comment: Its `sales_order_place_after` event. If I throw an exception I won't b able to sav ethe order with `pending_payment`status. Would I? I need that so that for every failed payment transaction the store owner could see in the backend.

Comment: The `sales_order_place_after` event emits the order model, therefore you should be able to modifiy it before throwing the error, aborting the process - if this does not work, you could orderwrite `Mage_Sales_Model_Order::_placePayment` to include your own checks

Comment: I got this to work by adding the parameter true to this statement $order->setState(Mage_Sales_Model_Order::STATE_CANCELED,true); //or whatever distinct order status you'd like

Comment: Note: using setState() isn't updating inventory counts. I've switched to using $order->cancel() instead